# FBSDK startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler giving error 400

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve list of FB friends which use the app. It was working fine until last month. I just realized that it is not working any longer. I am using the following block to achieve the results:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
    }
    else
{
NSLog(@"%@",error)
}
    }];
```

But quite contrary to previous results, Now I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x174278280 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<PFReceptionist: 0x174026dc0>, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            message = "(#100) Unknown fields: username.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}}
```

Has the facebook sdk changed lately? It might be so because I can't get the gender and date of birth too now, which I was able to retrieve before. What do you reckon is the issue? How can I retrieve the friends who are using my app, as it is quite crucial for my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using this block instead.

```
FBRequest *friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me/friends"];
    [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary* result,NSError *error) {
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", result);
        }
    }];
```